# Data from excel not showing on plot when creating graph on website

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

```
#Graph 1 = Deceased                                     
data_url1 = r'/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/xxx.xlsx'                                   
df1 = pd.read_excel(data_url1, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet5')                                      
                                    
dff1 = df1.copy()
dff1 = dff1[dff1['Sources'].isin([checklist_val])]                                                                                                          
                                        
dff1_date = dff1['Date'].tolist()                       
dff1_old = dff1['No_of_Individuals_Old'].tolist()                                       
dff1_new = dff1['No_of_Individuals_New'].tolist()                                       
                            
fig1 = make_subplots(specs=[[{'secondary_y':True}]])                                        
fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=dff1_old,                                       
                          x=dff1_date,                                      
                          name='Deceased (Old)', 
                          mode='lines+markers', line={'dash': 'solid', 'color': 'red'}), secondary_y=False,)                                                                                
fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=dff1_new,                                       
                          x=dff1_date,                                      
                          name='Deceased (New)',                                        
                          mode='lines+markers', line={'dash': 'dash', 'color': 'red'}), secondary_y=True)                                       
                                    
fig1.update_traces(showlegend=True)                                     
                                    
fig1.update_layout(height=500,                                      
                    xaxis_title_text='Year',
                    barmode='group',                                        
                    template='simple_white',                                        
                    legend=dict(                                        
                        yanchor="top",                                      
                        y=1.15,                                     
                        xanchor="left",                                     
                        x=0.01))                                            

fig1.update_yaxes(title_text="No of Individuals", secondary_y=False)
```

Hey! Im new to python so please bear with me. I have been trying to import data from an excel sheet to plot a graph that would show on website, but only the radio buttons appear and an empty graph, the data does not appear. I was wondering if i made any mistakes in the code above? Any help would be deeply appreciated thank you!

Comment: Since you didn't present any data, I ran your code using the highs and lows of the stock price data. The graph was drawn correctly. There may be an issue with your data. Can you present sample data?

Comment: Expanded to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YDdL9YIdzABTZRW_C0OoBenFEcBvk-Yh?usp=sharing) for reference. Will disable this link if you confirm.

Comment: Hi! it says i do not have permission to save to the notebook could you please edit the settings to let me upload my data and code?

Comment: The above link is accessible to those who know the link, but cannot access it?

Comment: it says cannot save changes when i try to type stuff on it and upload files

Comment: You only have permission to refer to it, so please copy it to your own environment and check it. If you have further issues, please update the question. This link is just a tentative answer.